# SAF - Share file via mail after creation with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I updated my targetSdkVersion to 30, so I had to update my creation File with SAF (storage access framework).

I was able to create the file, to choose location, to get the Uri in result (it is in the form content://), but when I try to send file as attach, the file is not attached. Gmail for example show me a messagge "Unable to attach file".

Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks all

Here is my code:

```
int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 336;

    private void createFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "dettaglio_utente.pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void alterDocument(Uri uri) {
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().
                    openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                    new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(pdfBase64, 0);
            fileOutputStream.write(pdfAsBytes);
            // Let the document provider know you're done by closing the stream.
            fileOutputStream.close();
            pfd.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == WRITE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {

                if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri path = data.getData();
                    alterDocument(path);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.privacy_mail_subject));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.privacy_mail_body));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also added the DocumentProvider in Manifest as indicated by Android Documentation [StorageProvider](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/StorageProvider)

```
<provider
            android:name=".MyDocumentProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.documents"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

You add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` when you *provide* a `Uri` to somebody else.

So, with respect to your code:

- You can remove `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` from your `createFile()` method, as you are looking to *receive* a `Uri`
- You need to add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` to your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, before using that `Intent`, since you want to *provide* a `Uri` and you want the recipient to be able to read the contents identified by that `Uri`

Also:

- Remove `android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"` from your `<provider>`, as the other app (e.g., Gmail) most likely will not hold that permission
- Note that `resolveActivity()` may not work on Android 11+ without adding a `<queries>` element to your manifest — you might want to skip the `resolveActivity()` call and just wrap your `startActivity()` call in a `try`/`catch` and deal with the `ActivityNotFoundException`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CommonsWare

I removed `android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"` but it gave me SecurityException on launch.

So I resolved this way:

I removed all the node `<provider>` from Manifest, then I removed the following line from the email intent `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));` and replaced it with `intent.setType("message/rfc822");`

Now it works!!